# Gradle c++ project : win32 dependencies not included

Tags: c++, gradle, build.gradle

Im having an issue using gradle with C++. Specifically im building a native library spec in one project which uses win32 and opengl and trying to reference that static library from another executable test project.

The library gradle.build settings:

```
        repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {

            //defines the windows pre-built library, headers and .lib files

            windowsSDK {
                headers.srcDirs srcWindowsSDKDirName
                 binaries.withType(PrebuiltStaticLibraryBinary) {
                staticLibraryFile = file(srcWindowsSDKLibName+"10.0.16299.0/"+"um/"+"x86/"+"User32.Lib")

                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                            sharedLibraryLinkFile = file(srcWindowsSDKLibName+"10.0.16299.0/"+"um/"+"x86/"+"User32.Lib")
                        }

                }
            }

            windowsSDKGLU {

               headers.srcDir srcWindowsSDKDirName
                binaries.withType(PrebuiltStaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile = file(srcWindowsSDKLibName+"10.0.16299.0/"+"um/"+"x86/"+"GlU32.Lib") 
                }

                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                sharedLibraryLinkFile = file(srcWindowsSDKLibName+"10.0.16299.0/"+"um/"+"x86/"+"GlU32.Lib")     
                }
            }

            windowsSDKGL {

               headers.srcDir srcWindowsSDKDirName
                binaries.withType(PrebuiltStaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile = file(srcWindowsSDKLibName+"10.0.16299.0/"+"um/"+"x86/"+"OpenGL32.Lib")  
                }

                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                sharedLibraryLinkFile = file(srcWindowsSDKLibName+"10.0.16299.0/"+"um/"+"x86/"+"OpenGL32.Lib")      
                }
            }

            windowsSDKGDI {

               headers.srcDir srcWindowsSDKDirName
                binaries.withType(PrebuiltStaticLibraryBinary) {
                    staticLibraryFile = file(srcWindowsSDKLibName+"10.0.16299.0/"+"um/"+"x86/"+"GDI32.lib") 
                }

                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                sharedLibraryLinkFile = file(srcWindowsSDKLibName+"10.0.16299.0/"+"um/"+"x86/"+"GDI32.lib")     
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Those are the libraries the nativelibraryspec uses and that library project actually builds fine as expected and outputs a .lib and .dll.

From the NativeExecutableSpec (my test project) i try to include the entire project firstly:

```
lib project: ':mylibrary', linkage: "static", library: 'main'
```

This seems to work in terms of including the library itself - it finds the .lib or .dll. However it produces link errors:

```
main.lib(minimal.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ChoosePixelFormat@8 referenced in function "public: int __thiscall
```

and many more......

To try and test it manually I referenced the static library manually in the same manner i included the win32.lib files and included it into the project that way:

```
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {

            //defines the windows pre-built library, headers and .lib files

            mySDK {
                headers.srcDirs "mysdk/Shared/headers"
                binaries.withType(PrebuiltStaticLibraryBinary) {
                staticLibraryFile = file("mysdk/build/libs/main/static/main.lib")

                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                            sharedLibraryLinkFile = file("mysdk/build/libs/main/static/main.lib")
                        }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and included those libs in the test NativeExecutableSpec.

```
                        lib library: "mySDK", linkage: "static"
```

Both methods of trying to link a static library that reference those windows libraries seems to cause link errors and im unsure why...the library itself as i mentioned compiles however the test executable fails to link as it cannot seem to inherit the referenced lib's of that project.

I researched into possible causes but so far I cannot find a reasonable explanation as to why the library compiles but anything referencing the lib of that library does not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Murky, nothing like a tool like that to make simple link errors undiagnosable.  A static library project does not link any dependencies.  That doesn't happen until the library gets linked into the main project to produce the executable file.  The library dependencies listed in the first snippet don't do anything while building main.lib.  So declaring the dependency on main.lib is not enough, you'll also have to link gdi32.lib to get the dependency on ChoosePixelFormat resolved.

Comment: So the dependency that the library part of my project uses, cant be resolved by the executable without explicility linking the dependencies to both the library and the executable? i.e  windows binaries are referenced by the library, but the exe needs to also reference them after referencing the library anyway? it doesent inherit the library dependency for the .libs? If this is the case im even more confused....as how does another project in gradle list my library as a dependency if it too will have to manually link to the windows libraries after pulling my library....

Comment: That is correct.  A static library is simplistic, nothing but a bag of the object files produced by the compiler.  The linker does not get involved at all while that library gets built.

Comment: I guess my next question would then be, how do i link in the resources into the static library such that other projects can reference it the lib (my sdk) without having to be explicit about the dependencies? or would it be a case of generating a list of objects that must be linked when the project referencing my lib is compiled?

Comment: It is technically possible to embed a link instruction in the .lib so the linker knows that it also needs to link another .lib to stay happy.  But that has a strong tooling dependency, the opposite of what gradle tries to do.  #pragma comment(lib, "gdi32.lib") for MSVC.

Comment: That actually solved it and helped me understand why it wasnt working. If you post it as an answer i will accept it as it explained why it didnt work as well as let me bridge the gap until i find a way to include the .libs into my artefacts to use as a library.